# for-loops update correct textfield to the correct column in a database (parse)

Tags: ios, objective-c

When a textfield gets edited i set the textfield object as "True" in a NSDictionary.
Then a for-loop checks for the textfields that has been edited. The edited textfields gets updated to a database using Parse. I want so that my for-loop knows what textfield should update what column in my database. the for-loop should check if it should update as int or string aswell. is this possible?

My code:

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveRecipe:(id)sender{
for (NSNumber *key in allEditedTextfields) { //Loop through all keys

    if ([[allEditedTextfields objectForKey:key] boolValue] == TRUE) { //See if it was edited

        UITextField *tField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:[key intValue]];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Recipe"];
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:detailId block:^(PFObject *recipe, NSError *error){

        if (tField.tag == 110) {
            recipe[@"recipeName"] = recipeName.text;
        }
        if (tField.tag == 111){
            recipe[@"recipePrepTime"] = recipePrepTime.text;
        }
        if (tField.tag ==112){
            recipe[@"recipeRating"] = recipeRating.text; //recipeRating is an integer
        }
        }];

    }
}

[allEditedTextfields removeAllObjects];
```

}

Comment: you can pass tField.tag as a parameter and then your loop will know exactly what to update.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly regarding `recipe[@"recipeRating"]` make sure you conver recipeRating.text int an NSNumber otherwise it can't be saved to Parse.

Next with regards to parse updating the right columns, parse makes it very easy. Simply call `[recipe saveInBackground]` and parse automatically detects what you have changed and updates. You don't have to tell it to update a specific column

Comment: So you mean i should delete the "if-statement" and recplace it with "[recipe saveInBackground]"?

Comment: Oh no. The if statement does exactly what it should. Simply add the `[recipe saveInBackground]` at the end of the if statement (before you close it)

Comment: But if i have like 20 if-statements, will this not make the App itself take alot of memory or cpu-usage?

Comment: 20 if statements isn't a problem for an app. I usually have loops and if statements that surpass that number so you have nothing to worry about

Comment: I just gotta thank you so much for helping me out!! Have a great night!